# Comment upvote/flag buttons are vertically-aligned in middle instead of top

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, comments

I noticed that the upvote/flag buttons for long comments are vertically aligned in the middle instead of the top. Was this intentional? It's different from Stack Overflow. I find it a little more difficult to use, but I don't know if that's because it's a worse design or just because it's different from what I'm used to.

I've tested on FF and Chrome for WinXP.

[image]

For comparison, here's what you see on Meta Stack Overflow:

[image]

Comment: I came to post the same thing.... I even had nice screenshots prepared -- but now I must content with this comment and with upvoting this post.

Comment: Oh well, *I* came to post the same thing, too, but I can't even leave a comment — I must content with upvoting @Juan's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put in a fix for this. It will be in the next deployment.